# Remove price on Magento product page

Tags: php, magento, frontend, google-search

I'm trying to hide the value on the product page, it's hidden on the page, however it's showing up in Google's results and I do not want it.
When I see the source code of the page, the TAG still stays there:

```
<span class = "price" itemprop = "price"> 45.12 </ span>
```

I commented the price tag on the following files:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/new.phtml
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

But still unsuccessful.
Is there any other place where I need to comment/remove this TAG?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use .css file.

```
style="display:none"
```

Or

if not, go to

```
design/your_theme/default/layouts
```

and create here file

```
local.xml
```

code of it will be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="product.clone_prices"/>
    </default>
```

Comment: or go to theme that you use, and find <price-box> tag , comment it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this TAG <price-box> encounter where?
What about the .css where is this file?

Comment: ok, let`s go.  Pls say to me what theme do you use? because magento first went to your current theme folder, after to daefault and then to base.

Comment: if not, go to design/your_theme/default/layouts and create here file local.xml.

Comment: or go to /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml and find :      <div class="price-box"> , comment it

Comment: Ok...thanks alexey boltynov I tried this: go to /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml and find: <div class = "price-box">

but it still did not work, I do not know if it's cache

Comment: go to magento directory , folder /var/  and delete everything that located here.  There are will be /session , /cache etc.  Drop this files

Comment: go to admin panel , system/cache managment/ select all types of cashe and press disable , press buttons there , that have name flush cache.   Also try another browser, use private browsing ( cntrl + shift + N ), delete all browsing data from yours browser like cache,cookie,history etc.

Comment: if you have real site, not local, give me please url, or go teamviewer if you have it. i can help you.  alexeyboltynov@gmail.com

Comment: alexey boltynov thank you very much for the attention, I will try these other options that you suggested.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I managed to solve the problem, it was this: as I was maintaining the site / store I was a little lost, there were many themes and duplicate files.
I was the subject of the theme looking for the TAG (as I'm not very used to the file structure of Magento I sifted a little bit) but I found and removed it (commented) and it worked.
On the issue of Google submit in the results, I believe that there is still time to not submit more.

And again thank you.

Comment: Good job :)  Pls , vote up , and press to answer if I helped you :)